# Localize iPhone app to support Irish

Tags: iphone, localization

I'd like to support multiple languages in one of my apps. I don't have a problem with the localization for the supported languages, but I'd also like to support Irish (Gaelic).

Is this a case of overriding NSLocalizedString, checking an app variable for the user's selected country, and calling localizedStringForKey, passing in the relevant strings file as the table?

Is there a better way? Are there significant issues with this approach?

Can someone point me in the right direction please?

Thanks

Jez

Answer (score 0):

Select a file you would like to have an Irish version of...

If you go to the right-hand-side editor (xCode 4) and hit the page-looking tab...

Go down to "Localizations" and hit the + sign...

Keep going down to "Other"...

And find "Irish"...

It will create a second version of the file you had selected and you can change all of the NSStrings etc. to Irish.